# How do you select multiple elements for a javascript click event to be captured on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="outsideContainer">
<ul>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Goodbye</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With jQuery how would I say when any of those elements is clicked execute a certain function?

I had this but it did not work:

```
$('#outsideContainer').click(function() {
//do stuff
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That should work fine... see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/jUysR/

Comment: Nothing wrong here , what do you mean your question title is complicated :?

Comment: just figured out what was wrong... I was looking for the event.target to be just the `outsideContainer` instead of the `ul` and `li`s

Comment: It's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question, and then accept that answer (you have to wait two days, but other than that)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not include the javascript that was actually causing the problem (it was in the `//do stuff`, but the problem I was having was I was looking for the event.target to be just the outsideContainer instead of the `ul` and `li`s.

Answer (score 4):

For the most part that's fine. Possible reasons it wouldn't work:

1. You're executing your JavaScript before the "outsideContainer" element exists, e.g.:

   ```
   ...
   <script>
   $('#outsideContainer').click(function() {
   //do stuff
   });
   </script>
   <div id="outsideContainer">
   <ul>
   <li>Hello</li>
   <li>Goodbye</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   ```

   The element must exist as of when the script is called. Either just put your `script` block at the very end of the page, just before the closing `body` tag, or wrap your code in a function you pass into jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.
2. You're expecting `this` within your callback to refer to the `li` element; in fact, it will refer to the "outsideContainer" `div`, because that's what the event handler is hooked to. You can get at the `li` element via `event.target`:

   ```
   $('#outsideContainer').click(function() {
       // here, this is the raw "outsideContainer" element
       // and event.target is the raw element that was clicked
   });
   ```

   Note that depending on your margins and padding, `event.target` might be the `ul` element, if you click within the `ul` but not on a `li`.

Other things that may be worth looking at:

- [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) - Hook an event on a container but have jQuery filter the events you get depending on what child was clicked.
- [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) - Basically document-wide `delegate`.

Comment: thanks, indirectly you helped me because I was looking for the event.target to be just the `outsideContainer` instead of the `ul` and `li`s

Comment: @chromedude: LOL! I didn't consider that case. You might want to look at the links I added, although it sounds like you're there now.

Answer (score 1):

This will only fire when you click on the entire div.

```
$('#outsideContainer').click(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

To capture a click on each individual `li` do:

```
$('#outsideContainer ul li').click(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by T.J. Crowder, what you have works, but you will want to be aware of the context of `this`.  Substituting `event.target` for `this` will give you the actual element that was clicked.

As a demonstration, I have included below a fiddle that will alert the node (tag) type and text content of the clicked element.  The `<div>`, `<ul>`, and `<li>`s all have different colored borders to help you visually determine what you are actually clicking on.

[Live demo ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/JU6YP/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('outsideContainer ul li').click(function() {
//stuff
});
```